# How to handle lot's of potential choices from user

Tags: java, android

I am in the process of learning android/java and I am creating an application that does conversions. The issue that I am running into is that there are a lot of different combinations that can be made as the user has to select a unit to convert from and one to convert to. I need a solution that can determine which unit has been chosen so I can do a calculation with values that are assigned to each unit. Here is the code.

Thanks in advance for any response.
Dom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Conversions"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:text="Weight"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weight"
        >

    </Spinner>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/to">

    </Spinner>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/weight"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spin1"
        android:text="-->"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/val1"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_below="@id/spin1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/to"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/val1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spin1"

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/spin2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        />


</android.widget.RelativeLayout>`

Java:

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner spin1 = findViewById(R.id.spin1);

        String[] items1 = {"Gram", "Kilogram", "Stone", "Tonne", "Pound", "Ounce",};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items1);
        spin1.setAdapter(adapter1);

        Spinner spin2 = findViewById(R.id.spin2);


        String[] items2 = {"Gram", "Kilogram", "Stone", "Tonne", "Pound", "Ounce",};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items2);
        spin2.setAdapter(adapter2);




    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for suggestions on User Interface design here?  Or do you need help getting your chosen design  to work?

Comment: The UI is a working progress which I can change. It is the java which I am struggling to get my head around. The logic on how to handle so many different combinations that could be entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm envisioning an app that converts an input distance between different units of measurement (feet, miles, meters, etc...). Here's what I'd do:

Create two variables of type double, called `inputConversionFactor` and `outputConversionFactor`. When the user selects an option from each spinner, this sets the corresponding conversion factor value.

When an input distance is entered, internally convert this distance to meters using `inputConversionFactor`. Then use `outputConversionFactor` to convert from meters to the desired output unit.

By doing it this way, you're breaking down the problem into two discrete steps. You don't have to worry about how to convert between any two arbitrary units, since you're always converting the input to meters and then the meters to the output unit type.

Comment: How do I determine whether the user has chosen "stone" or "kilograms"? I could use if statements but that would be a lot of if statements. Thanks for your comment

Comment: You use an onItemSelectedListener on your Spinner. You could avoid a ton of IF statements by implementing a custom adapter for your Spinner and creating a custom class to hold your measurements and conversion factors, but that'll complicate things.

Comment: I see. So to not complicate things would you recommend that I go for the if statements?

Comment: If you're just starting out, yes. But I would recommend that you get well acquainted with creating custom adapters soon because that's one of the most common things you'll be doing in Android. This would allow you to create a backing array that stores each spinner item's name and its corresponding conversion factor. It would just be more succinct and more scalable: http://www.zoftino.com/android-spinner-custom-adapter-&-layout